# Tls using classic asp to send mail

Tags: asp-classic

Is any possibility to use TLS to send mail using ASP classic using a free lib?

I have used CDO but i think that not allow TLS.

Thanks for all, and sorry for the question. I can send mail using Gmail without problem, but now i need to send mail using a server that only allow Tls authentication. I dont find in the api or in internet the way to send a mail using TLS.

```vb
    Function bCorreoEnviarGeneral(objCorreo, bPorSeparado, sSep, sMailFrom, sMailTo, sAsunto, sCuerpo, sBCC, sAdjunto)
dim i,j,iNumDest
dim bSalida
dim Mailer
dim arrayMailTo
dim objMessage
dim ArrayBCC
dim mailFrom,mailSmtp,mailUser,mailPassword,mailSSL,mailPort

call DatosServidorCorreo (mailFrom,mailSmtp,mailUser,mailPassword,mailSSL,mailPort)

on error resume next

   Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory.
   Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).

  Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
  Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
  Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM

  Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
  objMessage.Subject = sAsunto
  objMessage.From = "SIG"

if sMailFrom<>"" then
    objMessage.From  = sMailFrom
else
    objMessage.From  = mailFrom
end if

 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

 'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = mailSmtp
 'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
 'Your UserID on the SMTP server
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = mailUser
 'Your password on the SMTP server
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
  ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = mailPassword

'Server port (typically 25)
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = mailPort

 'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = mailSSL

'Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection      to the SMTP server)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

 '==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

if instr(lcase(sCuerpo),"<html>")<>0 then 
    objMessage.HTMLBody = sCuerpo
else
    objMessage.TextBody = sCuerpo
end if

if sAdjunto<>"" then
'      arrayAdjuntos = Split(Adjunto,sSep)
'      for i=0 to uBound(arrayAdjuntos)
      objMessage.AddAttachment sAdjunto 'arrayAdjuntos(i)
'     next
end if

if session("idpersona")=1038 then
   if sAdjunto<>"" then Response.Write "<br>"+sAdjunto+"<br>"
end if
    arrayMailTo = Split(sMailTo,sSep)
    iNumDest = ubound(arrayMailTo)

if iNumDest < 0 then
    objMessage.To = sMailFrom
    objMessage.Send 

    if err.number = 0 then
       'if propCorreoVerMensajes then Response.Write "Mail enviado..."
      else
      bSalida = false
      Response.Write "Envío de mail fallido. El error es " + err.description + mailSmtp
    end if

elseif bPorSeparado then


  for i=0 to iNumDest

   objMessage.To = arrayMailTo(i)

    if i=iNumDest and trim(sBCC)<>"" then
       arrayBCC = Split(sBCC,sSep)
       for j=0 to uBound(arrayBCC)
          objMessage.BCC  = arrayBCC(j)
       next
    end if

    objMessage.Send 
    if err.number = 0 then
      ' if propCorreoVerMensajes then Response.Write "Mail enviado..."
       else
      bSalida = false
      Response.Write "Envío de mail fallido. El error es " + err.description
    end if
  next
     else

  if trim(sBCC)<>"" then
     arrayBCC = Split(sBCC,sSep)
     for i=0 to uBound(arrayBCC)
      objMessage.BCC = arrayBCC(i)
     next
  end if

  for i=0 to iNumDest
    objMessage.To = arrayMailTo(i)
  next

on error resume next

  objMessage.Send 

  if err.number = 0 then
    'if propCorreoVerMensajes then Response.Write "Mail enviado..."
  else
     bSalida = false
     Response.Write "Envío de mail fallido. El error es " + err.description
  end if
on error goto 0
   end if

   set objMessage = nothing

 bCorreoEnviarGeneral = True
  End Function
```

Comment: show code.. why do you think there will not be any TLS in CDO? you might want to take a look at [microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555287/de) and [microsoft technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/a2c5eac0-4954-441c-9fe6-9561f474f311/relaying-email-with-authentication-and-tls?forum=onlineservicesexchange)

Comment: If you use a server that allow SSL/Tls you are only allow ssl but the mail can be send because you have the options (like gmail) the problem is for example with outlook.office365.com that only allow Tls and not support ssl.

Comment: so what error do you get? (after remoing the `on error resume next` ofc..

Comment: Transport Error connecting to server. This only occurs when i tried to use server that only allow TLS, with Gmail all works properly.

Comment: What port are you using with TLS set to true?  I've had that transport error message with 587, but it worked when I switched to 25.  I found a blog by someone who discovered the same [- http://blog.clicdata.com/2012/07/13/sending-smtp-mail-via-office-365-exchange-using-cdo-message-and-other-applications/

Comment: Because 587 for example in Outlook only allow TLS and not TLS/SSL as Gmail, to solve the problem you must use another lib, the problem is that there aren´t any free lib for that, if you want to check is you have another problem, try for example aspemail (free for 30 days)  that allow to use TLS.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use port 25?

Comment: Yes, my boss want to use 587....... But now thwe problem is solve.. i must use a pay lib for that, and try with other server diferent to office365, because office365 only allow to send mail to clients that have an account, for example if i try to send a mail using a from of an gmail account like that address is not office, you will have a failure (yes my boss wants that the application dont using call send a mail using a from that dont exist........ with 1&1 for example you can do this).

Comment: Too my boss want to allow SSL, TLS or without encript... for that i use to diferent libs to send the mail ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code you allow, send with SSL, TLS, without them, attach one file, send to multiples address, send without BCC..... the only problem is that you need to use ASPemail lib of pay.

```
function DatosServidorCorreo(mailFrom,mailSmtp,mailUser,mailPassword,mailTLS,mailPort,mailSSL)
dim sql,reg


set BD=session("conn")

'BD="Provider=MSDASQL.1;Data Source=dsnSig;Extended Properties=Chr(39)DSN=dsnSig;DBQ=C:\bd\SIG_Tecnoy_BBDD.mdb;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;Chr(39)"
sql="select * from SIG_PARAMETROS"
if not BDRegCrear(BD,reg,sql) then
    call dialogo ("Error conexión BD")
    call BDErrorMostrar("No se puede acceder a los datos del servidor")
    DatosServidorCorreo=false
    exit function
end if

do while not reg.eof
    if trim(reg.fields("Nombre")) = "MailFrom" then 
        mailFrom = trim(reg.fields("Valor"))
    elseif trim(reg.fields("Nombre")) = "MailSmtp" then
        mailSmtp = trim(reg.fields("Valor"))
    elseif trim(reg.fields("Nombre")) = "MailUser" then
        mailUser = trim(reg.fields("Valor"))
    elseif trim(reg.fields("Nombre")) = "MailPassword" then
        mailPassword = trim(reg.fields("Valor"))
    elseif trim(reg.fields("Nombre")) = "MailTLS" then
        mailTLS = trim(reg.fields("Valor"))
    elseif trim(reg.fields("Nombre")) = "MailPort" then
        mailPort = trim(reg.fields("Valor"))
    elseif trim(reg.fields("Nombre")) = "MailSSL" then
        mailSSL = trim(reg.fields("Valor"))
    end if
    reg.movenext
loop

set BD=nothing

call BDRegLiberar(reg)
end function


   Function bCorreoEnviarGeneral(objCorreo, bPorSeparado, sSep, sMailFrom, sMailTo, sAsunto, sCuerpo, sBCC, sAdjunto)
dim i,j,iNumDest
dim bSalida
dim objMessage
dim Mail
dim mailFrom,mailSmtp,mailUser,mailPassword,mailTLS,mailPort,mailSSL

call DatosServidorCorreo (mailFrom,mailSmtp,mailUser,mailPassword,mailTLS,mailPort,mailSSL)

on error resume next


  if (mailTLS = "True" ) then

    ' Envio de correo con encriptacion TLS


    bSalida = true
    Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
    Mail.Host = mailSmtp
    Mail.Username = mailUser
    Mail.Password = mailPassword
    Mail.Port= mailPort
    Mail.TLS = mailTLS
    Mail.Subject = sAsunto
    'Mail.AddAddress sMailTo
    Mail.From  = mailFrom

        ' Si manda el sistema el correo el remitente será el recogido en la BBDD, si el remitente es un usuario el remitente será ese usuario

        if sMailFrom<>"" then

                Mail.From  = sMailFrom
        else

                Mail.From  = mailFrom
        end if

        ' Los mensajes pueden ir en texto plano o en formato html con el siguiente IF si el mensaje es HTML se le atribuye a la propiedad booleana IsHTML el valor True (False por      defecto en texto plano)


        if instr(lcase(sCuerpo),"<html>")<>0 then 

            Mail.IsHTML = True
            Mail.Body = sCuerpo
        else

            Mail.Body = sCuerpo
        end if

        ' Sistema de archivos adjuntos (Solo uno como máximo por correo)

        if sAdjunto<>"" then
                Mail.AddAttachment sAdjunto 
        end if


        arrayMailTo = Split(sMailTo,sSep)
        iNumDest = ubound(arrayMailTo)


if session("idpersona")=1038 then
   if sAdjunto<>"" then Response.Write "<br>"+sAdjunto+"<br>"
end if
    arrayMailTo = Split(sMailTo,sSep)
    iNumDest = ubound(arrayMailTo)

if iNumDest < 0 then

    Mail.AddAddress sMailFrom
    Mail.Send 

    if err.number = 0 then
       'if propCorreoVerMensajes then Response.Write "Mail enviado..."
    else
      bSalida = false
      Response.Write "Envío de mail fallido. El error es " + err.description + mailSmtp
    end if

elseif bPorSeparado then



  for i=0 to iNumDest
        'Para cada uno de los destinatarios en la matríz, enviamos un mensaje
   Mail.AddAddress arrayMailTo(i)
    'Si se envian los mails por separado, sólo se envia con copia el último, porque sino
    'a los destinatarios en sBCC les llegarían n correos repetidos:
    'Se añaden los Bcc en el último puesto que no hay posibilidad con éste objeto de borrar(clear)
    'el recipiente de Bcc.
    if i=iNumDest and trim(sBCC)<>"" then
       arrayBCC = Split(sBCC,sSep)
       for j=0 to uBound(arrayBCC)
          Mail.AddBcc arrayBCC(j)
       next
    end if

    Mail.Send 

    if err.number = 0 then
      ' if propCorreoVerMensajes then Response.Write "Mail enviado..."
    else
      bSalida = false

      Response.Write "Envío de mail fallido. El error es " + err.description
    end if
  next
      else


  'Destinatarios con copia:
  if trim(sBCC)<>"" then

     arrayBCC = Split(sBCC,sSep)
     for i=0 to uBound(arrayBCC)
      Mail.AddBcc arrayBCC(i)
     next
  end if

    Mail.AddAddress sMailTo


on error resume next

  Mail.Send 

  if err.number = 0 then
    'if propCorreoVerMensajes then Response.Write "Mail enviado..."
  else
     bSalida = false
     Response.Write "Envío de mail fallido. El error es " + err.description
  end if
on error goto 0
end if
set Mail = nothing


    else

        ' Mensaje con encriptacion SSL o libre de ella.


        bSalida = true
        Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1 'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory.
        Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).

        Const cdoAnonymous = 0 'Do not authenticate
        Const cdoBasic = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
        Const cdoNTLM = 2 'NTLM

        Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
        objMessage.Subject = sAsunto
        'objMessage.To = sMailTo


        if sMailFrom<>"" then

                objMessage.From  = sMailFrom
        else

                objMessage.From  = mailFrom
        end if

        objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
        ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

                 'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
   objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
   ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = mailSmtp
  'Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
   objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
     ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic
     'Your UserID on the SMTP server
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
     ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = mailUser
      'Your password on the SMTP server
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = mailPassword

    'Server port (typically 25)
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = mailPort

   'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
  objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = mailSSL

 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
  ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 120

      objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update

    '==End remote SMTP server configuration section==

if instr(lcase(sCuerpo),"<html>")<>0 then 
    objMessage.HTMLBody = sCuerpo
else
    objMessage.TextBody = sCuerpo
end if

if sAdjunto<>"" then
'      arrayAdjuntos = Split(Adjunto,sSep)
'      for i=0 to uBound(arrayAdjuntos)
      objMessage.AddAttachment (sAdjunto) 'arrayAdjuntos(i)
'     next
end if

if session("idpersona")=1038 then
   if sAdjunto<>"" then Response.Write "<br>"+sAdjunto+"<br>"
end if
    arrayMailTo = Split(sMailTo,sSep)
    iNumDest = ubound(arrayMailTo)

if iNumDest < 0 then
    objMessage.To = sMailFrom
    objMessage.Send 

    if err.number = 0 then
       'if propCorreoVerMensajes then Response.Write "Mail enviado..."
    else
      bSalida = false
      Response.Write "Envío de mail fallido. El error es " + err.description + mailSmtp
    end if

elseif bPorSeparado then


  for i=0 to iNumDest
        'Para cada uno de los destinatarios en la matríz, enviamos un mensaje
   objMessage.To = arrayMailTo(i)
    'Si se envian los mails por separado, sólo se envia con copia el último, porque sino
    'a los destinatarios en sBCC les llegarían n correos repetidos:
    'Se añaden los Bcc en el último puesto que no hay posibilidad con éste objeto de borrar(clear)
    'el recipiente de Bcc.
    if i=iNumDest and trim(sBCC)<>"" then
       arrayBCC = Split(sBCC,sSep)
       for j=0 to uBound(arrayBCC)
          objMessage.BCC  = arrayBCC(j)
       next
    end if

    objMessage.Send 
    if err.number = 0 then
      ' if propCorreoVerMensajes then Response.Write "Mail enviado..."
    else
      bSalida = false
      Response.Write "Envío de mail fallido. El error es " + err.description
    end if
  next
  else

  'Destinatarios con copia:
  if trim(sBCC)<>"" then
     arrayBCC = Split(sBCC,sSep)
     for i=0 to uBound(arrayBCC)
      objMessage.BCC = arrayBCC(i)
     next
  end if 
    objMessage.To = sMailTo

on error resume next

  objMessage.Send 

  if err.number = 0 then
    'if propCorreoVerMensajes then Response.Write "Mail enviado..."
  else
     bSalida = false
     Response.Write "Envío de mail fallido. El error es " + err.description
  end if
on error goto 0
end if
set objMessage = nothing

    end if

    bCorreoEnviarGeneral = bSalida

 End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for external libs.

Change

```
'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
 ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = mailSSL
```

with

```
'Use TLS for the connection (False or True)
 objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendtls") = mailSSL
```